# Spark structured streaming: How to merge new data and result

Tags: apache-spark, merge, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark to process streaming data, and I need to union new data with the processed data,for example，I have grouped and sorted data:

```
val groups = data
.groupBy("room_ID").agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct($"room_date",$"readout"))).as("subRecord"))
```

groups:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  | subRecord                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1   |[[2013-12-14 00:00:00, 10], [2013-12-14 01:00:00, 15], [2013-12-14 02:00:00, 20], [2013-12-14 03:00:00,  5], [2013-12-14 04:00:00, 30], [2013-12-14 05:00:00, 35]]|
|  2   |[[2013-12-14 00:00:00, 30], [2013-12-14 01:00:00, 35], [2013-12-14 02:00:00, 45], [2013-12-14 03:00:00, 55], [2013-12-14 04:00:00, 65], [2013-12-14 05:00:00, 70]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to delete the record`[2013-12-14 03:00:00, 5]`of id:1,which means i have to compare each point with those around it,so I use an udf to do this

```
val clearNoise:UserDefinedFunction = udf(
//do clear noise
)
val result = groups.withColumn("cleard",clear($"subRecord"))
```

result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  | cleard                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1   |[[2013-12-14 00:00:00, 10], [2013-12-14 01:00:00, 15], [2013-12-14 02:00:00, 20], [2013-12-14 04:00:00, 30], [2013-12-14 05:00:00, 35]]|
|  2   |[[2013-12-14 00:00:00, 30], [2013-12-14 01:00:00, 35], [2013-12-14 02:00:00, 45], [2013-12-14 03:00:00, 55], [2013-12-14 04:00:00, 65], [2013-12-14 05:00:00, 70]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

my question is,will spark process all the data again when new data comes,if so,how can I just merge new data and the latest 2 point of each id in the result without process the old data again? In otherwords,the output of the last batch is the input of the next batch.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will have a new file for your new data. 
If both the RDDs have the same structure you can do a join of your existing RDD with the new one you are going to create with new file.

```
val MergedRDD = result.union(newRDD)
```

This will merge the results of Both RDDs to one, without having the old data processed again.

However, if your incoming data is streaming, you can better use [DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/api/streaming/spark/streaming/DStream.html)

Its best when you have streaming data coming in.